# netshel paypal configration error

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

I made all configration in the https://packagist.org/packages/netshell/paypal
to make payment with paypal 
but I have this error

> FatalErrorException in paywithpaypal.php line 15: Class
>   'App\Http\Controllers\PayPal' not found

this is the code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use PayPal;
use Redirect;
use App\Http\Requests;


class paywithpaypal extends Controller {
    private $_apiContext;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_apiContext = PayPal::ApiContext(
            config('services.paypal.client_id'),
            config('services.paypal.secret'));

        $this->_apiContext->setConfig(array(
            'mode' => 'sandbox',
            'service.EndPoint' => 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com',
            'http.ConnectionTimeOut' => 30,
            'log.LogEnabled' => true,
            'log.FileName' => storage_path('logs/paypal.log'),
            'log.LogLevel' => 'FINE'
        ));

    }

    public function getCheckout() {
    $payer = PayPal::Payer();
    $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

    $amount = PayPal:: Amount();
    $amount->setCurrency('EUR');
    $amount->setTotal(42); // This is the simple way,
    // you can alternatively describe everything in the order separately;
    // Reference the PayPal PHP REST SDK for details.

    $transaction = PayPal::Transaction();
    $transaction->setAmount($amount);
    $transaction->setDescription('What are you selling?');

    $redirectUrls = PayPal:: RedirectUrls();
    $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl(action('paywithpaypal@getDone'));
    $redirectUrls->setCancelUrl(action('paywithpaypal@getCancel'));

    $payment = PayPal::Payment();
    $payment->setIntent('sale');
    $payment->setPayer($payer);
    $payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);
    $payment->setTransactions(array($transaction));

    $response = $payment->create($this->_apiContext);
    $redirectUrl = $response->links[1]->href;

    return Redirect::to( $redirectUrl ); }

public function getDone(Request $request) {
    $id = $request->get('paymentId');
    $token = $request->get('token');
    $payer_id = $request->get('PayerID');

    $payment = PayPal::getById($id, $this->_apiContext);

    $paymentExecution = PayPal::PaymentExecution();

    $paymentExecution->setPayerId($payer_id);
    $executePayment = $payment->execute($paymentExecution, $this->_apiContext);

    // Clear the shopping cart, write to database, send notifications, etc.

    // Thank the user for the purchase
    return view('checkout.done'); }

public function getCancel() {
    // Curse and humiliate the user for cancelling this most sacred payment (yours)
    return view('checkout.cancel'); } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must not have added

```
'aliases' => array(
    // ...
    'Paypal' => 'Netshell\Paypal\Facades\Paypal',
)
```

to `app/config/app.php` in the `aliases` array as mentioned in the [docs](https://packagist.org/packages/netshell/paypal).

Also, you may try changing the line

```
use PayPal;
```

to

```
use Netshell\Paypal\Facades\Paypal;
```

in your `paywithpaypal` controller.